Zod custom validation for non empty value
I have a simple form to create a new shop for customers.
My issue is this, I have a select option with a value of 'nill' and I want zod to show an error message if this option is selected.
This is my zod schema
categoryId: z.string().min(1, 'Shop category is required!')

So how do I add a custom validation that also returns the message 'Shop category is required!' if the selected value is nill. I am new to zod and know of refine but I don't know how to implement it

You need to use the .refine() method to add a custom validation.
const schema = z.object({
  categoryId: z
    .string()
    .min(1, {message: 'Shop category is required!'})
    .refine((value) => value !== 'nill', {
      message: 'Shop category is required!',
    }),
});

Or,
But in this case, you may not a refine(); you can achieve the same result by,
const schema = z.object({
  categoryId: z
    .string()
    .nonempty({message: 'Shop category is required!'})
    .refine((value) => value !== 'nill', {
      message: 'Shop category is required!',
    }),
});

The .refine() method in Zod is typically used for more complex, custom validation logic that goes beyond the basic constraints like string length or presence. It's perfect for scenarios like- Validating one field based on another field's value.

Thank you. It works but if i change the category Id back to "nill" after switching it , the message goes away and acts as if the input field is validated

Fixed it. Thanks
